# Powershell number conversions

Tags: powershell

I have been getting some questionable results from using number conversions in powershell.
example:
$somenumber / 1tb.
This should return a value in terabytes from my understanding, but seems it is returning the number in tebibytes in some cases.
so I did an output of the conversion values. My question is, are the values the conversions return, in bytes or kilobytes? Knowing this would go a long way into answering my question. I can provide more info if needed.

```
PS C:\Users\mjohnsonad> 1tb
1099511627776
PS C:\Users\mjohnsonad> 1gb
1073741824
PS C:\Users\mjohnsonad> 1mb
1048576
```

Comment: I think it's a fair assumption that tera/tebi is used interchangeably in this context (FWIW there's a `kb` multiplier as well `= 1024`). I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "are the values the conversions return, in bytes or kilobytes?" - they're numbers, they represent whatever you mean them to represent :)

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. I mean the number 1099511627776 from the return of tb. is that number in bytes or kb? Also, when I am calculating storage usage, there can be quite a difference between tebi and tera when you get into triple digit range.

Comment: the numbers for those constants are based on 1024, not 1000.